# In R - Check vector elements in another vector and write occurrences

Tags: r, vector, indexing, match

I have the following dfs reporting the occurrences of some codes in week 1 and week 2

This for Week 1:

```
w1 <- data.frame("Code" = c("B00F328AFW", "B0792HCFTG", "B071SDVC6Z", "B0792H8GHP", "X000MLAQUJ"), "Occs" = c(31, 23, 19, 18, 16))

# Code      # Occs
B00F328AFW      31
B0792HCFTG      23
B071SDVC6Z      19
B0792H8GHP      18
X000MLAQUJ      16
```

And this for Week 2:

```
w2 <- data.frame("Code" = c("X000VID7DV", "X000MLAQUJ", "B000FNFSPY", "X000Z94DWZ", "B01I3DT21I", "X000SC7OO3", "B00F328AFW", "B071SDVC6Z"), "Occs" = c(27, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 15, 14))

# Code      # Occs
X000VID7DV      27
X000MLAQUJ      21
B000FNFSPY      20
X000Z94DWZ      20
B01I3DT21I      19
X000SC7OO3      19
B00F328AFW      15
B071SDVC6Z      14
```

I would like to understand whether the codes from the first week are present in the second week and how many occurrences (if they are more or less compared with the previous one).

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea on how to proceed, I've just tried to use the %in% function comparing the first columns of the dfs but the result is very far what I expect.

Comment: It would be much more helpful for people trying to answer your question if you provided code to easily allow them access to your data sets! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution.

```
library(dplyr)

w1 %>% inner_join(w2, by = "Code") %>% 
mutate(compare = case_when(
                  Occs.y > Occs.x ~ "more",
                   Occs.y < Occs.x ~ "less",
                   Occs.y == Occs.x ~ "same")) %>%
  rename(Occ_week1 = Occs.x, Occ_week2 = Occs.y)

Code           Occ_week1    Occ_week2    compare
1 B00F328AFW        31        15       less
2 B071SDVC6Z        19        14       less
3 X000MLAQUJ        16        21      more
```